# Grails ui-performance plugin page compression issue

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am using Grails 2.0.1 in my website. Everything was fine until I installed grails ui-performance plugin into my website.

When I am deploying war with this new plugin the css files cannot be accessed. The web pages are rendered without the css and when I "view source" the page and try to access the generated url (versioned) of the css files I get the following error in firefox

"The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression."

After installing this plugin I have only changed the way I call the css to my page.
Like this:

```
 <p:css name='main'/>
 <p:css name='style'/>
```

Am I missing something. Please help

Comment: Do you have the resources plugin installed (it's in `BuildConfig.groovy` by default in 2.0.x)? I'm pretty sure they're not compatible.

Comment: Yes, I have not installed them manually but they are by default in BuildConfig.groovy. But now what to do. What is the actual issue? I am totally stuck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall one of them. Either don't use UI Performance, or remove resources by deleting the line in `BuildConfig.groovy` that declares the dependency. Note that there are plugins that work with resources and add in functionality like what UI Performance has, so one option is to keep resources and uninstall ui-performance, and add one or more of these to `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.4"
```

Comment: Burt you mean to say that : 1) The plugin ui-performance is not compatible with grails 2.0.1. 2) Installing this three plugin(zipped,cached and yui-minify) will solve all my need to use ui-performance plugin.

Comment: I haven't tested ui-performance in a 2.x app but I have no reason to expect that it wouldn't work. But the resources plugin and the addon plugins like zipped-resources, etc. are becoming a standard for 2.x apps. I haven't used those much so I'm not sure if there's anything missing from the ui-performance feature list.

Comment: Thanx Burt :). I was completely unaware of the plugins u mentioned above. When i went thru the documentations provided for the above plugins I actually came to know what resource plugin does. The following url helped me a lot http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/guide/1.%20Overview.html . though installing them was not so easy... as I have to manually change the version of each and every dependent plugins to install them.... well any how now my purpose is solved. thanx once again.